# Proper way to play Ghostly Possession Enchantment Aura?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When playing [Ghostly Possession](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220052), since it would make the enchanted creature useless by both preventing all combat damage that would be dealt by and also dealt to enchanted creature then what is the purpose of even giving the creature flying?

Not fully understanding the proper way to utilize this card or the benefits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you play it on your own creature, you now have a flying blocker that can't be dealt damage. That's not 'useless' at all. If you play it on an opponent's creature, you can stop it from dealing damage, in exchange for giving them a really good blocker.

Comment: Would the enchanted creature still deal dmg or just make it a good blocker which can not kill any attackers? I seen the damage dealt by as both attack and block damage.

Comment: @Damainman, Something prevented does not happen. It does not deal damage. It cannot be dealt damage.

Answer (score 0):

The coolest thing I've seen in limited was enchanting an Geist of Saint Traft. Geist's Angel is a sepprate object to the game and not effected by the enchantment.

Comment: That's definitely another good use. :)